# Store a list of controller instances in a different controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I need an angular example of one controller wrapping the other one.
As an example, I want to split some logic between `EndpointListController` and `EndpointController`.

`EndpointListController` will have the means of getting the data from storage, plus some functions applicable on the entire list, `EndpointController` however, will have the logic for one individual endpoint.

It would be really nice to loop through them with ng-repeat and call the methods directly on the endpoint, like this:

```
<table ng-controller="EndpointListController">
    <tr ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints">
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="endpoint.select()"></td>
      <td>{{endpoint.label}}</td>
      <td><span class="label label-info">2014-10-10 23:59</span></td>
      <td><span class="label label-success">success</span></td>
      <td><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

currently I'm forced to do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints" ng-controller="EndpointController" endpoint-data="{{endpoint}}">
```

Not very elegant ...

Is the thing I'm trying to accomplish even possible with angular? Probably I'm looking at this wrong, if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want your endpoint $resource in a factory that manages that data 1) as a singleton that can be injected wherever, and 2) $resource managed CRUD to make that data available.

Comment: I think your "endpoint" should be a directive and not a controller

Comment: just use a directive, `ng-repeat` already creates a child scope

Comment: Yes, these are all correct, technically your $resource should be a factory, and a directive should manage your widget like `<table end-point-list>` and your controller should belong to that directive. Then you have a child directive for each endpoint `<tr end-point>`.

Comment: ok, I see, thank you all for your comments. So my initial design was wrong from the beginning... Can someone give me an example and submit it as an answer, so I can count it as the answer?

Comment: My 5 cent, usually I use a controller (in a ng-repeat) to filter the data for  better performance and it's best practice. Try to check in Batarang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the container directive like this

> Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPa3nHZ9aXemfKJSiYgZ?p=preview)

You shorten your widget code down to something like this:

```
<end-point-list class="table">
  <end-point ng-repeat="ep in endpoints" scope="ep" func="selectEp(scope)">
  </end-point>
</end-point-list>
```

and you have 2 directives where one requires the other like

```
app.directive("endPointList", function(..
 return {
   controller:'EndpointCtrl',
//
app.directive("endPoint", function(..
   require:'?^endPointList',
```

So you have isolate scope on the children but are able to pass anything back to the controller.

I left out the part where this connects to any actual endpoints, not sure if that was part of the question?

Comment: yes please, can you add the parts where it connects the endpoints?

Comment: huh, Ok, changed the link.  Now the endpoints what you trying to connect?  Are you making like a list of POST, GET, PUT to display a RESTful interface? like http://swagger.io/?

Comment: no, I'm saving the endpoints to the local storage, but I think I might need to know how to do it with a rest api later, can you show how to do that as part of the answer as well?

Comment: Also, you mentioned a factory, is it to retrieve data and construct resources?

Comment: Ok I updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KPa3nHZ9aXemfKJSiYgZ?p=preview to add a resource per item. A factory, service, provider etc, are all services that work as a singleton among other things, and they are the more common approach to returning a $resource,  but in your case you need multiple in 1 repeat so we put them in the directive.